# How do I retrieve all attributes of a .NET method using NDepend?

Tags: .net, ndepend

I would like to retrieve (using NDepend) a list of all attributes of a given type that are declared on a method.  Something like

```
warnif count > 0 from m in JustMyCode.Methods where 
  m.HasAttribute("MyNamespace.MyAttribute")
select new { m, m.Attributes("MyNamespace.MyAttribute")  }
```

Is this possible?  Is there a radically different way of doing this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to understand completely the question.

If you mean that a method is tagged with several occurrences of `MyNamespace.MyAttribute` NDepend won't give more info than `true` for the expression `m.HasAttribute("MyNamespace.MyAttribute")`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am indeed looking for multiple occurrences of `MyNamespace.MyAttribute` on a method.